# Why do I see gaps between pixmap tiles in QGraphicsView when I enable Antialiasing

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

I am using QGraphicsView framework to display a big image from smaller QPixmap tiles. I also want to enable Antialiasing since the scene will contain line items. Why do I see gaps between the tiles when I enable Antialiasing?

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*);

private:
    QGraphicsScene* _scene;
    QGraphicsView* _view;
    qreal _scale;
    static const int _imageWidth = 512;
    static const int _imageHeight = 128;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    _scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    _view = new QGraphicsView(_scene, this);

     //this causes gaps to appear ?
    _view->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    _scene->setBackgroundBrush( QBrush( QColor( Qt::lightGray ) ) );

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(_view);

    setWindowTitle(QString("GapsBetweenTiles- QT Version %1")
       .arg(QT_VERSION_STR));

    QImage img = QImage(_imageWidth, _imageHeight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    img.fill(QColor(00, 50, 50));

    int offset = 0;
    for (int k=0; k < 10; ++k) {
        QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixitem = _scene->addPixmap( 
                          QPixmap::fromImage(img));
        pixitem->setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        pixitem->setPos(0, offset);
        offset += _imageHeight;
    }
    _scale = 1.0;
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* )
{
    int scaledWidth = (qreal)_view->width() -
                           _view->verticalScrollBar()->width() ;
    qreal scale = (qreal)scaledWidth / (qreal)_imageWidth;
    qreal scaleMult = scale / _scale;

    _view->scale(scaleMult, scaleMult);
    _scale = scale;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The gaps appear when scaled image height (`_imageHeight * scale`) becomes fractional.
Each `QGraphicsPixmapItem` is drawn as a separate object. If such object has fractional height the border is smoothed when anti-aliasing enabled (fractional bordering line is partially painted).

There are three possible gap layouts in your case:

- no gaps if scaled image height is integer
- periodic series of 1 object with gap and 1 without gap if fractional part of height is 0.5
- periodic series of 3 objects with gaps and 1 object without gap if fractional part is 0.25 or 0.75; here the 2nd gap is brighter than the 1st and 3rd gaps.

So, if you want perfect object alignment the scaled height should be integer.
In your example the scaled height is integer when scaled width is divisible by 4.
It can be verified by adding into `resizeEvent` the following line:

```
    scaledWidth = (scaledWidth / 4) * 4;
```

---

By the way, you can disable anti-aliasing only for `QGraphicsPixmapItem` objects by removing the line:

```
    pixitem->setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```